# Hello $timeout in Angular

Tags: angularjs, timeout, promise

I was reading *Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS* book, and in the chapter 3 when the autors took about $q and promises they write and example of a single $timeout.

**index.html**

```
<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.name = $timeout(function () {
  return "World";
}, 2000);
```

The thing is that i test the code and this don't work for me, i don't if i write some wrong, i write it and look it several time but i don't know where is the error.

I change the code in the controller for:

```
$timeout(function () {
     $scope.name = "World";
}, 2000);
```

and work perfectly.

Anyone know why this happened?, I include a plunk of the example [here](http://plnkr.co/ldEL3a1TD584HHb6tcTV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because timeout returns promise, not a string. return inside callback returns what will be passed along the chain.

Correct way of using it would be:

```
$timeout(function () {
          return "World";
    }, 2000).then(function(p) {
      $scope.name = p;
    });
```